# Способы уменьшения числа запросов к базе данных

Tags: оптимизация, база-данных, архитектура, sql

Проект, над которым я сейчас работаю, организован как некий каркас, который обрастает модулями. Практически каждый модуль - это получение данных из БД или запись в БД. Внутри самого модуля тоже может быть несколько запросов: надо проверить данные, и - в зависимости от результата проверки - что-то записать или изменить.

Интересно, какие есть способы, позволяющие уменьшить число запросов к базе. Писать данные в локальное хранилище? сессии? куки? кэширование? хаки в SQL-запросах?

Ну и еще: возможно ли такое соотношение одна страница = один запрос к БД? при том, что данные реально разные.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вы в принципе все способы и перечислили. Основной - кеширование.

> возможно ли такое соотношение одна
> страница = один запрос к БД? при том,
> что данные реально разные.

Очень абстрактный вопрос. Он решается на уровне существующего приложения.

Судя по вопросам, вы совершаете типичную ошибку начинающего - "оптимизация на спичках". Задумываетесь об оптимизации, еще не зная узких мест приложения.

Answer (score 4):

Как правило, основной принцип оптимизации - это сделать так, чтобы количество запросов не зависело от количества данных. Т.е., не было такого, что у Вас получается большая таблица, обходятся её строки, и при обработке каждой из них делаются мелкие запросы. Если без этого не обойтись, можно, например, строки обрабатывать группами, скажем, по 1000 штук. Обращаю внимание, что речь идёт именно о мелких запросах, для которых обращение к БД более ресурсоёмко, чем собственно выполнение запроса.

Модули, по идее - это не данные, их в приложении фиксированное количество. Можете попробовать создать объектную модель запроса, которая будет строиться модулями по кирпичикам (если, конечно, у Вас все запросы от разных модулей для одной операции идут к одной таблице).

Answer (score 0):

Очень хороший вариант — описывать логику приложения (проекта) в СУБД, тогда можно будет избавиться от всяких "конструкторов" и "велосипедов".

Comment: Можно поподробнее? Небольшой пример или ссылки тоже интересны.

Comment: @Khvorostin, подробнее я бы описал конкретную задачу. В первую очередь важно иметь представления (views) в БД и выбирать информацию только из них. Представления могут быть служебными для внутренних выборок и общими, которые используются для отображения данных пользователям.

Comment: @Khvorostin, К задаче.
Например, реализацию регистрации договора нет смысла делать на стороне клиента, выполняя различные проверки на существование такого договора или такого клиента и прочее. Проще и правильнее передать всё, что было введено в форму регистрации договора на клиенте, вызывая хранимую процедуру БД, а уже на стороне СУБД выполнить все проверки, причём, возможно, одним-двумя запросами, после чего сохранить договор и клиенту вернуть его ID и обновить выборку (список договоров).

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос очень сферический и очень в вакууме. "У меня тут есть что-то с модулями, оно запросы делает, надо оптимизировать".

На универсальный вопрос могу ответить только универсальный ответом. Используй кеширование. Где как и что кешировать -- зависит от специфики приложения, про которую неизвестно ничего.

> Ну и еще: возможно ли такое
> соотношение одна страница = один
> запрос к БД? при том, что данные
> реально разные.

Это называется денормализация. Такой подход предлагают многие не-реляционные (NoSQL)базы данных. Естественно это противоречит реляционной модели данных, это несёт некоторые дополнительные риски.